# What sort of surfaces trigger Elemental Affinity?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I'm trying to decide if Elemental Affinity is a talent worth taking. Would standing on plain ground reduge my Geomancer skill costs, or would I need to be standing in oil/poison to achieve that effect? What are all the different surfaces that trigger it and how how can I deal with the negative effects they have, if any? How often do these surfaces appear in-game and how easy is it to create them?

Answer (score 2):

I did not take this talent myself when I played through the game so I do not know how effective it is, but I can tell you about the surfaces.

**Put simply, the elemental surfaces are a core part of the game.**

They appear very frequently, and there are specific spells in each school that create these surfaces or conditions (sometimes as a side effect, sometimes as the primary effect of the spell). The game isn't shy about being "video-gamey" and placing breakable barrels/containers filled with the various elemental stuffs. Even if you are at a lack for spells and containers, you can loot or buy spell scrolls, which are quite common, to create the desired effect. As long as you put a little forethought into how you plan on using your abilities, you will have no problem securing a reliable way to produce the elemental surface you want.

**However, most of them require you to be on a hazardous surface of some kind.**

Frankly, not enough research has been done on this talent, which is incredibly surprising given how long the game has been out.

**Geomancer** skills require you to stand on ooze or poison clouds, which both poison you. I believe it also works with oil, which slows you. All of these things are highly flammable.

**Hydrosophist** skills require you to stand in water puddles, or for it to be raining which is easily doable with one of the starting skills. This is by far the safest school for the talent. You don't need to be near the action where the blood puddles are and you can create your own surfaces extremely easily with Rain.

**Pyrokinetic** skills require you to be standing on fiery ground -- looks like lit coals. It probably also works when you are personally on fire.

**Aerotheurge** skills require you to be standing in electrified water. This is a harsh one because you will be stunned. Leaving your mage stunned and vulnerable is not exactly the best strategy.

A small secret: **Witchcraft** skills, despite not being strictly elemental, will be reduced in cost if you stand on a puddle of blood. Good for melee hybrid characters, since physical weapons produce that the most reliably.

Others that I haven't experimented with, but *seem like* they should be effective for at least one element include steam clouds (result from using water spells on a fire effect). I couldn't find anything online about other effects either.

These things are still hazardous and can still harm you, but from my understanding there's a talent that negates damage from environmental effects specifically, and it's not that hard to get items with resistances specific to the things you plan to be standing in.

In conclusion, you will find yourself with no lack of opportunities to use Elemental Affinity. It seems like a fairly safe option to me as a build choice, because resistances are always useful anyway and so is being immune to environmental hazards. 1 AP reduction is something you can go without but it's also a quite helpful bonus.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but I'd really like to see a list of surfaces that trigger it, how to deal with their effects and how to create them. I expect the attractiveness of this talent will depend a lot on which schools of magic you're going to be using.

Comment: Well, each elemental school of magic has its own environmental effect, in fact I believe they all have more than one. I am pretty sure it is equally effective regardless of which element you choose, barring any difficulties you might have with particular environmental effects (maybe you like the slow effect you get from oil more than the burn damage you take from burning surfaces).

Comment: There are likely factors beyond the mere presence of elemental surfaces, such as how common these surfaces are, how much AP it costs to create them, how long they persist, what sort of effect they have on those who stand in them, the general usefulness of the skills that create those surfaces, how much levels in a skill you need to learn the spells that create those surfaces, etc.

Comment: On the plus side, every school has a 'shield' spell which will make getting the Elemental Affinity bonus much easier, usually by making you immune to the element in question. It also raises your resistance by 50; you will be healed by an element if your resistance is over 100. Also, the Aerothurge x5 unlockable talent Lightning Rod makes you immune to stun, which makes standing in electrified surfaces a mega-shield from melee characters.